# Как убрать ошибку в пагинации redbeanphp?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

```
$pn=1;

$pp=10;

$all=R::findAll('users','ORDER BY login DESC LIMIT'.(($pn-1)*$pp)., .$pp );

//Передача страницы и разбивка на страницы по лимиту:       
$userses=R::findAll('users', 'ORDER BY login');

$all=array_slice($userses,(($pn-1)*$pp),$pp,true);

//Поиск всех страниц:

$userses=R::count('users');
$pc=ceil($userses/$pp);

$range = $pc-1;

$first=$pn-1-($pn-2)%$range;
$last=$first+$range<$pc?$first+$range:$pc;




 <div class="nav-links">
<?php if ($pn>1): ?>
  <a class="prev page-numbers" href="<?= pagelink($pn-1) ?>">Newer</a>
<?php endif; for ($i=$first; $i<=$last; $i++): if ($i==$pn): ?>
  <span class="page-numbers current"><?= $i ?></span>
<?php else: ?>
  <a class="page-numbers" href="<?= pagelink($i) ?>"><?= $i ?></a>
<?php endif; endfor; if ($pn<$pc): ?>
  <a class="next page-numbers" href="<?= pagelink($pn+1) ?>">Older</a>
<?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```

> Строка в которой ошибка:
>
> $all=R::findAll('users','ORDER BY login DESC
>   LIMIT'.(($pn-1)*$pp)., .$pp );
>
> Ошибка:
>
> Parse error: syntax error,
>   unexpected ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\qvinciy\index.php on line 185

---------------------Правки вопроса-------------

> После исправлений ошибок появилась другая.
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\qvinciy\index.php:200 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\qvinciy\index.php on line 200

```
200 строка $first=$pn-1-($pn-2)%$range;
```

Comment: Ошибку прочтите, на 185 строке у вас лишняя запятая..

Comment: Избавился от ошибки, изменив строку в конце

  $all=R::findAll('users','ORDER BY login DESC LIMIT'.(($pn-1)*$pp), $pp );

Но теперь другая появилась


Fatal error: Uncaught RedBeanPHP\RedException: Expected array, integer given. in C:\xampp\htdocs\qvinciy\libs\rb.php:8660 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\qvinciy\libs\rb.php(10824): RedBeanPHP\Finder->find('users', 'ORDER BY login ...', 10) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\qvinciy\index.php(185): RedBeanPHP\Facade::findAll('users', 'ORDER BY login ...', 10) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\qvinciy\libs\rb.php on line 8660